# Python-2.7.2 on 6.2 PUIAS i386_64

Tags: python, redhat

I am not a regular Linux user so this might be completely trivial question. I am running  6.2 PUIAS version i386_64 on one of my GPU based "super" computers due to the unavailability of NVidia drivers for NetBSD. The installed version of Python is 2.6.6. I need 2.7.2 Python and newer version of scipy, numpy, matlibplot and friends. I have PUIAS and EPEL repositories enabled. However they do not have newer versions of Python. What is the "recommended" way to install newer version of Python without braking the system which depends on it. I am not interested in Python 3.2 due to the lack of libraries for scientific computing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question. For people who are using Python for scientific computing on RedHat clones (PUIAS for example) the easiest way to get all they need is to use rpm package manager and [Enthought Python Distribution (EPD for short)](http://www.enthought.com/). EPD installs everything in a sandbox so system tools which are based on an obsolete version of Python are not massed up. However, paths have to be adjusted for system or even easier on the user base so that the using shell invokes non-system tools. One should never compile Python from source unless you are interesting in Python itself or in porting it to your favorite operating system rather than in your own research!

Answer (score 1):

When the [install-Python-from-source routine](http://docs.python.org/using/unix.html#building-python) tells you to use `make install`, type `make altinstall` instead. This will leave the normal `python` executable untouched and instead create `python2.7` for you to use. Install the other packages from source using this new executable. Don't forget to change the shebang line in your scripts accordingly.

Comment: I know how to install things using "source routine" but frankly speaking that not the way to do it at least not on BSDs. In order to use source, one would need to create proper Makefile with patches, checksums and ets. That make take a month of a hard work. Are you telling me that the only way to have Python 2.7.2 on PUIAS is to build from vanilla source? That is crazy.

Comment: Linux is not a BSD. And people build Python from source on RHEL all the time.